# Yarn install in gitlab pipline

Tags: gitlab, yarnpkg, gitlab-ci-runner, yarn-v2, gitlab-runner

I'm using pipline to install my packages and this is my script:

```
default:
  image: node:latest
  before_script:
    - yarn

Install Dependencies:
  stage: install_deps
  script:
    - yarn
```

and I got this error:

> error An unexpected error occurred:
> "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@ant-design%2ficons: tunneling socket
> could not be established, statusCode=407".

What is the problem? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The runner that you are running on - Is that a private runner for your project? 407 means when its trying to reach to the internet, its hitting up against a proxy which requires authentication. You can verify this easyly by running curl on that URL and see the response.